# Extract Subdirectory from a URL in Excel

Tags: excel

I'd like to do the following in Excel:

> http://subdomain.domain/subdirectory/url.php --> subdomain.domain/subdirectory

subdirectory or any text after / and before the next /

I already searched for formulas or add ins online but can't seem to find any formula for this. I only found a formula for subdomain.domain and url location.

I'm currently trying to modify this formula, but I just can't figure out how!:

> MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,8),LEN(A1)+1-FIND("/",A1,8))

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some nice people from MrExcel.com forum gave me this formula that works really great! I hope you can make use of it as well:

> =TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("//",A1)+2+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("//www.",A1)),4),LEN(A1))&"/","/",REPT(" ",999),2),999))

Answer (score 3):

That was a doozy! But this will work:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))/LEN("/")))-1),"http://",""),"https://","")
```

It will find the last occurrence of `/`, capture everything before it, then remove `http://`

**Updated** to work for both http and https.

Comment: @pnuts no, but has the added benefit of working for site.domain.com/subfolder/anotherfolder/thisfoldertoo

Comment: Thanks! This works well for sites without subdirectory and captures the domain instead, but my problem is it doesn't work for secured sites. :-/

Comment: do you need it to work with both? or just https? just change `http://` at the end to `https://`

Comment: Is there any way it can only capture the first occurence of / after domain? So it will only return subdomain.domain/subdirectory instead of subdomain.domain/subdirectory/url/url ? Thank you so much for all the help! :)

Comment: You'd probably need to use pnuts example then if you only want the first slash, but then wrap it in SUBSTITUTE instead of MID/LEN?

Comment: Thanks! Some nice people gave me a formula that does it! Thank you so much for the  help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Along the right lines I'd say. Maybe:

```
=MID(A1,8,FIND("/",MID(A1,8,LEN(A1)),FIND("/",MID(A1,8,LEN(A1)))+1)-1)
```

but the `8` would not work for some sites (possibly replace it with `FIND("//",A1)+2`).

Comment: Thanks! It didn't worked for https so I tried adding 1 and made it 9 and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I just tried it on another site that doesn't have a subdirectory such as this: http://www.placementhotline.com/resources.html and it returns an error. Sorry for my lack of knowledge in this. :-/ But i'm definitely learning. I will be using this in a bunch of urls for deduping purposes. Is it possible to make it work for urls without subdirectory as well? Thank you so much!

Comment: Tried a few urls. I think the other formula does it as well but it captures the domain only, which is good enough as it only means it doesn't have a subdirectory. However, the other formula doesn't work for secured sites. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what did the trick for me in English:

`=IFERROR(MID(A3,FIND("/",A3,9),FIND("/",A3,FIND("/",A3,9)+1)-FIND("/",A3,9)),"")`

And for Dutch Excel:

`=ALS.FOUT(DEEL(A3;VIND.ALLES("/";A3;9);VIND.ALLES("/";A3;VIND.ALLES("/";A3;9)+1)-VIND.ALLES("/";A3;9));"")`